# Grouping countries and years

Tags: typescript, iteration

Here is an input array that contains country name, year and value. I need to group values by country and years.

I use this approach that works for me, but I wonder how to optimize it:

```
export function collect(
  data: any[],
  years: string[] = ['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '2024']
) {
  const countries = new Map<string, any>();

  data.forEach((item) => {
    const { country, year, value } = item;
    countries.set(country, {
      ...(countries.get(country) || {}),
      [year]: value,
    });
  });

  const result: any[] = [];

  countries.forEach((_, key) => {
    const res = [];
    years.forEach((year) => {
      const values = countries.get(key);
      if (values) {
        const value = values[year] || 0;
        res.push(value);
      }
    });

    result.push({ data: res, label: key });
  });

  console.log(result);
}
```

As result I get an array. The number of elements are equal the number of `countries`. And the number of `data` is equal to the length of `years`.

```
[
 {
  data: [100.6, 105, 0, 0, 0]
  label: "A"
 }...
]
```

Probably it can be done with one loop instead of three.

Comment: Do you have an example input for reviewers to look at (and perhaps try)?  It could help you get the best review.

Answer (score -1):

```js
type TInputData = {
    country: string,
    year: number | string,
    value: number,
    
}[]

export function collect(
    data: TInputData,
    years: string[] = ['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '2024']
  ) {
    const result = {}

    for(const input of data){
        if(!result[input.country]){
            result[input.country] =  years.map(y => 0)
        }
            
        years.forEach((find_year, i) => {
            if(+find_year === +input.year)
                result[input.country][i] = input.value
        })
    }

    console.log(result);
}
```

Use example

```
const data: TInputData = [
    {
        country: 'UK',
        year: 2020,
        value: 500
    },
    {
        country: 'Egypit',
        year: 2021,
        value: 450
    },
    {
        country: 'Australia',
        year: 2022,
        value: 480
    },
    {
        country: 'Russia',
        year: 2023,
        value: 600
    }
]
collect(data)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really offer much for the OP. Please (re-) read [The help center page _How do I write a good answer?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Note it states: "_Every answer must make at least one **insightful observation** about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"